# Adding a Maven project to Eclipse compiled project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to add java code from a Maven project (called `docx4java`) which I checked out from svn to an existing Eclipse project (called `DocumentManager`). I have tried the normal way, that I thought would work, i.e.:

Right Click on `eclipse project>Properties>Java Build Paths> Projects > Add` (here I add the Maven project) and `>Libraries` (here I specify Native Library location e.g. `docx4/trunk/docx4/src/`) but I still can't get the 'Maven' classes to be recognised in eclipse. I get the message

```
import docx4j.src.main.java.org.docx4j.convert.out.flatOpcXml.FlatOpcXmlCreator cannot be resolved
```

I have tried adding a test project that was compiled in Eclipse and that works fine, Eclipse seems to recognise it i.e. `import org.me.TestProject` works fine.

How can I get the code from the Maven project `docx4java` to work in the Eclipse compiled project `DocumentManager`?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate eclipse poject files (which you can just import into your Workspace) using the maven [eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/)

Take a look at [these ecplise plugins](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) for a more direct integration of maven into eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You should create a eclipse project for docx4java as @Attila has commented. Once that is done, you should have two projects on your workspace: docx4java and DocumentManager. At this point, what you are doing now (adding a project reference to the Java Build Paths) should work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the source path is not configured correctly, this is why the compiler cannot find your "Maven classes".

> docx4java.src.main.java...

Maven has a different directory structure and you have to tell Eclipse where to find your sources.

For a "vanilla" eclipse project, remove the [standard eclipse build path](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm) *src* and add the maven source path *src/main/java* (or whereever you added the code), the compiler should correctly pick up your sources.

Note that you still have to add all jars mentioned in the dependencies section of the maven pom.xml file. Otherwise it won't compile, even if it finds your added java classes.

(Addendum: I would recommend to use maven in your existing project as well.)